# Script task output to check if condition

Tags: azure-data-factory, script-task

From the script task I get an output
{
"resultSetCount": 1,
"recordsAffected": 0,
"resultSets": [
{
"rowCount": 1,
"rows": [
{
"flag": 1
}
]
}
],

how to build an expression to check if the flag is 1

@equals(activity('Script1').output.resultSets.flag,1)
This is not working

Comment: Hi, can you try this `@equals(activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0]['rows'][0].flag,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this expression to get the required output value from script activity output in If Condition.

```
@equals(activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0]['rows'][0].flag,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

@equals(activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows[0].flag,1). May be needed to convert to int if you are setting with to variable and its type is string